# Question about proving distributive law of sets without venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From today I started to learn highschool math from a textbook

but there was only venn diagram based solution of this question

so I decided to prove it myself

Problem: Prove that A∪(B∩C)=(A∪B)∩(A∪C)

Proof

1. for all x such that x∈A∪(B∩C), then x∈A or x∈(B∩C)

in the case of x∈A
then x∈(A∪B) and x∈(A∪C)

in the case of x∈(B∩C)
then x∈(A∪B) and x∈(A∪C)

therefore A∪(B∩C)⊂(A∪B)∩(A∪C)

2.for all y such that y∈(A∪B)∩(A∪C)
then y∈(A∪B) and y∈(A∪C)

but A∪B means A or B, A∪C means A or C
so in the cases of y∈A and y∈A, y∈A and y∈C, y∈A and y∈B, then y∈A

in the case of y∈B and y∈C, then y∈(B∩C)

therefore (A∪B)∩(A∪C)⊂A∪(B∩C)

So A∪(B∩C)=(A∪B)∩(A∪C)

Is this right proof?(in highschool level)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Really?? Thank you so much for your answering! Actually i was very nervous while waiting the answer because of the "1 dislike" about this question
I'm not sure why though maybe because of the readability or something... but I feel relieved to hear that! I'm sorry for my emotional and personal reaction...(and using emojis...) I apologize If I made you feel uncomfortable
I can keep my focus on the study now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks good to me, too. The logic is fine, but the formatting and style don’t conform to the way “real” mathematicians like to write, and you didn’t use MathJax (because you didn’t need to, presumably). Maybe that was the reason for the down-vote. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: @bubba Thank you for saying so and Thank you for the explanation too

Comment: @bubba Ah! and Thank you for deleting one down-vote too! you are so nice

Comment: If you're going to post here more often, I strongly recommend you study https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference which will tell you how to format mathematics on this site so it's easier for other users to read.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the link! It helps a lot!